# Compile errors when I using CRT Memory Leak Detection

Tags: c++, new-operator

To detect memory leak, new keyword is re-defined.
It's OK if I use [Type 1]. But compile error is occured if I uncomment [Type 2].
Is there any way to use both type of new?

```
#include <crtdbg.h>

#define new new(_CLIENT_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)

struct Foo
{
 int m_N;
 Foo() : m_N( 0 ) {}
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
 _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
 _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN , _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
 _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);

 int* pI = new int( 1 ); 
 delete pI;

 Foo* pFoo = new Foo;    // [Type 1]
 //Foo* pFoo2 = new (pFoo) Foo(); // [Type 2]

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why so complex? Why not do it as described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3(VS.80).aspx ?

Comment: Did you have no problem with above code? Please try to uncomment "Type 2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your macro causes your placement new to expand to:

```
Foo* pFoo2 = new(_CLIENT_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__) (pFoo) Foo();
```

which is clearly invalid syntax.

A MSFT engineer [confirms](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/99818/vs-net-2005-stl-files-will-not-compile-if-new-is-defined-as-debug-new):

> `#define` of new is not compatible with placement new

so you can't use it with `crtdbg.h`.

Comment: However, pragma directive resolves this problem just focusing on compile.

Comment: #pragma push_macro( "new" )
...
#pragma pop_macro( "new" )